# Android Layout - Adding Dynamic Textview and EditText

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

In one of my project I want to create a layout like given Image

[image: Dynamic EditText and TextView]

In image assume that Red boxes are Textviews and Blue boxes are EditText 
The number of rows is not known. It depends on web service Response. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Have you looked at using a gridview at all? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: My problem is that I will be adding component dynamically through code. If it was through XML I can do it. If you can tell me how to add elements in grid view dynamically then It will be helpful for me

Comment: Gridview is dynamic, thats what the adapter is for. Please read the contents of that page completely.

Comment: ok. Thanks for your guidance. I will go through it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code generating site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this codes. Such as

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="First Row" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Ok" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Cancel" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I expect it will be helpful for you. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding views dynamically in linear layout which is inside scroll view.

Try this code.I know it is not exact solution.But,Hope it gives you some idea.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ScrollView scrollview;
    LinearLayout  linearLayout;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    static int i;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scrollview = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView view = new TextView(MainActivity.this);             
                view.setText(++i+" view");
                linearLayout.addView(view, layoutParams); 
            }

        });

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 first inf_child.xml layout:

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/inf_dynamicLl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="OK"/>
     <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="Cancel"/>

 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


second inf_dynamic_view.xml layout which will generate row dynamically:

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/inner_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
   >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secontText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ThirdText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />
 <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        />

</LinearLayout>



if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.inf_child, null);

        }

        LinearLayout dynamicLl = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inf_dynamicLl);

        for (int rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < parentData.get(groupPosition).childData.get(childPosition).price.size(); rowCounter++) 

                createRow(dynamicLl, parentData.get(groupPosition).childData.get(childPosition).price.get(rowCounter), groupPosition);


=> create row dynamically

private void createRow(LinearLayout lView, String price, int childPosition) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View l = vi.inflate(R.layout.inf_dynamic_view, null);

        final TextView tvFirst, tvSecond,tvThird;
         final EditText edt1;



        lView.addView(l);
        lView.refreshDrawableState();
    }
```